# Parsing data in DataFormat "chromium web custom mime data format" when dragged from browser to windows application

Tags: c#

I am writing an application where I have a drag (from browser) and drop (to windows app).

I am setting data by setData using javascript so that I can read that in windows app.

below is my JavaScript:

```
<header>Drag and drop test</header>
<div id="div1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Hi, try dragging me out</div>
<script lang="javascript">
    function allowDrop(ev) 
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) 
    {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("MyCustomDataFormatUrl", "https://myportal.com/documents/mydoc.docx");
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("MyCustomDataFormat", "https://myportal.com");
    }
</script>
```

When I finally drag it to windows app I read DataFormat "Chromium Web Custom MIME Data Format" as below in C# code:

```
var stream = (MemoryStream) e.Data.GetData("Chromium Web Custom MIME Data Format", true);
var stringValue = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

What I get in the StringValue is
**"à\0\u0002\0\u0015\0mycustomdataformaturl\0)\0https://myportal.com/documents/mydoc.docx\0\u0012\0mycustomdataformat\u0014\0https://myportal.com"**

Main issue is that I donot know how can I parse this in structured way to get my key and values from above string?

Does anyone has any idea?

I have tried multiple UniCodes to see if data is retrived in some parseable structure but did not get one ahich works properly.